# explode when use INNER JOIN

Tags: php, inner-join, explode

Trying to explode id's into option values with INNER JOIN function
Would you assist to find what is missing?
Below is my code:

```
 <select name="productSize" class="span8 tip" required>
 <?php  $query=mysqli_query($con,"select size.id,size.sizeName from size 
        INNER JOIN products ON size.id=products.productSize where 
        products.id='$pid'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {

    $size = $row['productSize'];
    $boom = explode(",", $size);
    foreach ($boom as $row){
        echo '<option value='.$row['id'].'>'.$row['sizeName'].'</option>'; 
    } ?>
  </select>
```

UPDATE: 
Thanks to guys pointing out on my mistakes, here is an updated code showing productSize comma-separated ID's as option values.

```
  <?php $query=mysqli_query($con,"select size.id, size.sizeName, 
         products.productSize from size INNER JOIN products ON 
         size.id=products.productSize WHERE products.id='$pid'");

         while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {

         $size = $row['productSize'];
         $boom = explode(",", $size);
         foreach ($boom as $row){

          echo '<option value='.$row['id'].'>'.$row['sizeName'].'</option>'; 
             }} ?>
```

However there is still an issue: need sizeName to be shown instead of ID's.
P.S. I am new to php so excuse me for such simple questions :)

Comment: What’s missing - from the question - is the actual problem description. Please go read [ask], then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: You're not selecting the `productSize` column in the query.

Comment: Do a `var_dump($row);` inside your loop, and you will see what the structure of that actually is.

Comment: @misorude Only first value is reflected in option, all the rest after "," are missing

Comment: And what _is_ the actual content of $size?

Comment: You're overwriting the variable `$row` in the inner `foreach` loop. You're also missing the `}` for the outer loop.

Comment: @Barmar I thought about it, but fail to write it correctly.. I mean not selecting productSize

Comment: You also shouldn't store comma-separated lists in database columns, you should normalize your data. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: You can use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to return it as a comma-separated list after joining with the table.

Comment: @misorude It should be array of sizeNames from productSize column (with size ids) of products table

Comment: I did not ask you what it _should be_, but what it actually is! Again, use var_dump or similar to make debug outputs, and _verify_ such things.

Comment: As @Barmar advised: You also shouldn't store comma-separated lists in database columns, you should normalize your data, I will not go on with comma-separated lists. Thank you a lot! How can I rate your answer? It really helped me.

Comment: @YelenaTsK Why do you expect to get anything from the `productSize` column if you don't have `size.productSize` in the `SELECT` list?

Comment: I didn't post an answer, there's nothing to rate.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 $query=mysqli_query($con,"select size.id, size.sizeName, 
         products.productSize from size INNER JOIN products ON 
         size.id=products.productSize WHERE products.id='$pid'");

         while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {

         $size[] = $row['productSize'];

         }

         foreach ($size as $res){

          echo '<option value='.$res['size.id'].'>'.$res['sizeName'].'</option>'; 
             }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?php
$query=mysqli_query($con,"select size.id, size.sizeName, 
         products.productSize from size INNER JOIN products ON 
         size.id=products.productSize WHERE products.id='$pid'");

         while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
         ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $row['size.id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['sizeName']; ?>/option>
         <?php


         }
?>
```